# How can I Find the stoichiometric coefficient of a complex chemical reaction??

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, chemistry

I'm trying to balance a complex chemical reaction of decomposition of an organic material.
I tried using Matlab to sole the set of equations I got, But the problem I get and where I think I'm missing up is that the reaction has 11 variables and once I put it into equations, I only get 4 equations as below:

The reaction : $$C_{40}H_{65}O_{25}N\rightarrow CO+CO_2+CH_4+HCN+NH_3+H_2+N_2+N_2O+NO_2+NO$$

Adding Variables [X] : $$X_0C_{40}H_{65}O_{25}N\to X_1CO+X_2CH_4+X_3H2+X_4NH_3+X_5HCN+X_6CO_2+X_7N_2+X_8N_2O+X_9NO+X_{10}NO_2$$

The goal is to find the values for $X$ coefficients using metrics in MATLAB in the form of $Ax=b$

The linear equations from the reaction:
\begin{align}
40X_0-X_1-X_2-X_5-X_6&=0\\
65X_0-4X_2-2X_3-3X_4-X_5&=0\\
25X_0-X_1-2X_6-X8-X_9-2X_{10}&=0\\
X_0-X_4-X_5-2X7-2X8-X_9-X_{10}&=0
\end{align}

I tried solving in Matlab, but I didn't get any values that made sense, where am I missing up ?!

Comment: Why didn’t the values make sense? Can you share the values you obtained?

Comment: Let's look at a much simpler example: $N_{99}O_{99}\to N_2O+NO_2+NO$. The trouble is, there isn't just one solution, there are many. $33N_2O+33NO_2$, $99NO$, $10N_2O+10NO_2+69NO$, etc., etc. When you have more unknowns than equations, you can't expect a unique solution.

Comment: to complete the system of equations, Can I assume values for the coefficient X4 to X10 to have a system of 11 equations.
Will this make any sense, And is assuming values governed by anything or assuming X=1 for all will result in a solution ?